# IONIC | Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at Promise

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I've got a project in Ionic. I want to run it, but when I am typing `ionic serve` it is giving me an error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/serve.js:445:26)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at IonicAngularServeCLI.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/serve.js:416:20)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code -13).
```

Comment: Somewhere you're trying to pipe something, usually an API response, and it is undefined. That is why you're getting this error. Would be beneficial to post your code so we can try and identify the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This error appears when you have a case in your code where an object containing the "pipe" property can be undefined. Look in your code where you are reading this property.

You can also post your code, so we can help you more easily.